# Parse.com one-to-one relationship Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

A general parse.com relationship question really - using swift.  I have a blogging app, for which there is a blog class, and a user class (along with a few others!)  the blog class stores the associated user ID in a field for simplicity.  Can I use includekey (or something similar) in a pfquery for the following;

firstly retrieve specific (or all) blog entries that match a criteria.
for each matching blog entry, check a field in the related user class for an option before returning the JSON list of entries

I suppose, sort of a subquery really, but wanted the whole thing to work in one pfquery if possible.

thanks!

Comment: would wherekey: matchesquery: help?

Comment: Is the user id stored as a string or a pointer ?

Comment: So you can't use include, but you may be able to create an additional query spec as you suggest

Comment: Is there a reason you have decided against using a pointer to the User class? If not, replace your String userid column with a new user Pointer column. This will enable you to use my solution AND you can make use of includeKey

Comment: as its really just user with UserID, and any relationship with the user entry would always be one-to-one I just decided to go with ID stored in both classes

Comment: i suppose adding a pointer to the user in the blog post shouldn't be too much of an issue to implement.   would the pointer be to the userID field in the user class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with a relational query. The user stored in blog should be a pointer.

First create a query for the field in the user class, i.e.

```
userQuery.whereKey("age", greaterThan: 30)
```

(Do not execute this query)

Then, when adding constraints to your blog query, add

```
blogQuery.whereKey("user", matchesQuery: userQuery)
```